# loop through array, returns odd and even numbers

Tags: javascript, loops

I am teaching myself code and am trying to solve this problem:

Write a loop that loops through nums, if the item is even, it adds it to the evens array, if the item is odd, it adds it to the odds array.

This is what I have so far:

```
var nums = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
var evens = [];
var odds = [];

var evenNumbers = function(nums) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if ((nums[i] % 2) != 1) {
            evens.push(nums[i]);
                console.log(evens);
        }
        else {
            odds.push(nums[i]);
                console.log(odds);
        }
    }

};

alert(evens);
alert(odds);
```

They don't return anything and I'm not sure where I'm going wrong, any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: You never call the function.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You're not actually executing the function.  You need to call evenNumbers();

```
var nums = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
var evens = [];
var odds = [];

var evenNumbers = function(nums) {
    for (var i = 0; i < nums.length; i++) {

        if ((nums[i] % 2) != 1) {
            evens.push(nums[i]);
                console.log(evens);
        }
        else {
            odds.push(nums[i]);
                console.log(odds);
        }
    }

};

evenNumbers(nums);
alert(evens);
alert(odds);
```

Comment: nope, `nums` and `nums` are 2 different things in this context. This crashes

Comment: Oh yes, I'll fix that.  Thanks!

Comment: FYI: (nums[i] % 2) != 1) will fail on all negative odd numbers. You have to do (nums[i] % 2) == 0) to work on all possible numbers

Answer (score 11):

I would recommend checking out the array.prototype.filter function with ES6 syntax:

```
const oddNumbers = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13].filter((number) => number%2!==0);
console.log(oddNumbers);
```

So elegant :)

Answer (score 3):

You aren't actually calling your function, just defining it.

call:

```
evenNumbers(nums);
```

before alerting the arrays

Comment: OP seems to be a rookie at js for now, it would be more helpful if you posted complete code so the OP can fully understand

Answer (score 2):

```
function groupNumbers(arr) {

  var arr = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

  var evenNumbers = arr.filter(number => number % 2 == 0);

  console.log("Even numbers " + evenNumbers);

  var oddNumbers = arr.filter(number => number % 2 !== 0);

  console.log("Odd numbers " + oddNumbers);
}

groupNumbers();
```

Comment: Please use [proper formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help)

Answer (score 0):

```
var rsl = {even:[], odd:[]};

[1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13].forEach(function(val,key,arr)
{
    var wrd = (val % 2) ? 'odd' : 'even';
    rsl[wrd][rsl[wrd].length] = val;
});

console.log(rsl);
```

Comment: In JavaScript, "integers" are called "numbers".
If you want to see the variable type name, use for instance:

    var foo = 123;
    console.log(typeof foo);

hope it helps ;)

Answer (score 0):

```
            //Even odd
            var arrays = [1,2,34,54,55,34,32,11,19,17,54,66,13];
            var result = arrays.filter((numbers)=>{
                 if(numbers%2!==0){
                   console.log(`${numbers} is not even`);
                 } else {
                     console.log(`${numbers} is even`);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a snippet :

```js
const arr = [24,42,543,676,456,535,555];
console.log("Values: "+arr);
var even = arr.filter((number)=>number%2 === 0);
console.log("Even Number: "+even);
var odd = arr.filter((number)=>number % 2 !==0);
console.log("Odd Number: "+odd);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Someone can try according to the way:**

```
function findOddEven(arr){
    let odd=[],even=[],i=0,j=0,k=0;
    for(i;i<arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%2==0){
          even[j++]=arr[i]
        }else{
            odd[k++]=arr[i]
        }
    }
    console.log("Even and Odd number",even,odd)
}

findOddEven([2,13,4,26,17])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function sortEvenOdd(arr, arrSize) {
  let odd = [];
  let even = [];
  for (let i = arrSize - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
    if (arr[i] % 2 !== 0) {
      odd.push(arr[i]);
    } else {
      even.push(arr[i]);
    }
  }
  even.sort(function (a, b) {
    return a - b;
  });
  odd.sort(function (a, b) {
    return b - a;
  });

  return [...odd, ...even];
}
```

// **return odd and even numbers** 
/* Sample Input 
7 
1 2 3 5 4 7 10

Sample Output
7 5 3 1 2 4 10

Sample Input 
7 
0 4 5 3 7 2 1

Sample Output
7 5 3 1 0 2 4      */